# what is the query to set a field in mysql

Tags: mysql, crud

I need a functionality for my project. There are 3 mysql tables.

```
Requests -  request_id, request_msg, user_id, request_datetime
Responses - response_id, request_id, response_msg, user_id, response_datetime, readflag
Users-      user_id, user_email, user_name
```

user post the requests and gets the responses from other users. [Very similar to stackoverflow site]

readflag in responses table indicate whether this response is read by the user who post the request associated with it or not?

```
0- NOT READ, 1-READ
```

Initially this field is 0, i want to mark it 1.

All requests listed on the same page. while user clicks on a requests all the responses associated with this request will be listed on other page.

Any user can read any user's requests and responses. while a user who posted the request reads the responses associated with it, i want to mark those responses only as readflag=1;

"UPDATE responses SET readflag = 1 WHERE request_id = '$request_id'" and  ..... ;

please help me out.

Comment: Well, what particular record are you trying to update?

Comment: @saluce -- i am trying to update all the responses. I want to set readflag field of responses table as '1'.

Comment: So the query you posted above would do that? What part do you need help with

Comment: …then you don't need the WHERE part of the query at all. Simply leave it out and all records will be updated.

Comment: All responses for a particular request?  All responses for every request by a user?  You need to know precisely what you want updated to know what your WHERE clause should be.

Comment: I dont want to update all the records. Any user can read any user's requests and responses. while a user who posted the request reads the responses associated with it, i want to mark them readflag=1;

Comment: Are all responses listed on the same page, or does the user need to click on each response individually to read them?

Comment: All requests listed on the same page. While user clicks on any of the requests, all the responses associated with it will be listed on other page. Now what i want is if this request is belongs to user who is logged in , mark all the responses for this particular request only as read =1;

Answer (score 1):

To update those records, you need to first have a variable that stores the userID, then check if the request belongs to that user.  If so, update all responses for that request.

```
$userID = "devesh";
$requestOwner = "devesh";

if ($userID == $requestOwner) {
    $qry = "UPDATE responses SET readflag = 1 WHERE request_id = '$request_id';
    // Execute query here
}
```

Comment: Hi saluce.. I am doing exactly same. First running the query to get user_id for that request.                                   $sql_query = "SELECT user_id FROM requests WHERE request_id = '$request_id'";                                                  Then comparing this user_id with loggedin user_id, if matched then running the same query given by you. but the problem is i have to run two queries in this case. I am looking for some solution, where only one query can perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you already display a Request and it's Responses I suggest you already know the request_id and the user_id. If the user_id belongs to the request_id the user_id belongs to the user that created the request. Therefore if you write

```
UPDATE Responses AS Res JOIN Requests as Req USING (request_id)
SET Req.readflag = 1
WHERE Res.request_id = '$request_id'
AND Res.user_id = '$user_id'
```

I'm using aliases for the tables here to distinguish between Req.user_id and Res.user_id.
If there is no record with request_id = '$request_id' and user_id = '$user_id' in the Request table, none of the responses are updated.

I think that the answer by saluce might well be faster because it works without a JOIN and only needs to be executed in some cases. So maybe you want to stay with what you've got.

Comment: You dont require condition if you want to update all rows. Just remove the WHERE condition